# Как в jQuery DataTables сделать фильтрацию столбцов?

Tags: jquery, datagrid, javascript, фильтры, dom

Фильтровать строки в DataTables можно [следующим образом](http://datatables.net/development/filtering#row_filters):

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        if ( aData[3] == 'ru' )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

А вот как отфильтровать столбцы? Например у меня есть столбцы (
http://jsfiddle.net/rejHy/
):

```
Дата   |      Город1      |      Город2      |      Город3      |
       | Доходы | Расходы | Доходы | Расходы | Доходы | Расходы |
```

Как сделать так чтобы при фильтрации по городам оставался только тот город который выбран, а все остальные столбцы исчезали? Например, если пользователь выбрал в фильтре городов Город1, то таблица должны измениться следующим образом:

```
Дата   |      Город1      |
       | Доходы | Расходы |
```

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понимаю, то при нажатии на любой из фильтров города1, все остальные города (2 и 3) должны исчезнуть вместе с их фильтрами? Безвозвратно?

Comment: Например есть комбобокс (назовем его фильтр городов) в котором есть Город1, Город2, Город3, Все_города. При выборе пункта Город1, все остальные города, т.е. столбцы Город2 и Город3 должны скрыться. При выборе в комбобоксе пункта Вся_города, должны отображаться все столбцы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/rejHy/1/). Единственно - надо программно считать количество столбцов (там, где комментарий *need to fix*). Ну это вам уже "домашнее задание" :)

HTML

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">Дата</th>
            <th colspan="2">Город1</th>
            <th colspan="2">Город2</th>
            <th colspan="2">Город3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Доходы</th>
            <th>Расходы</th>
            <th>Доходы</th>
            <th>Расходы</th>
            <th>Доходы</th>
            <th>Расходы</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2013.01.01</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>78</td>
            <td>91</td>
            <td>01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2013.01.02</td>
            <td>74</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>96</td>
            <td>35</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2013.01.03</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>69</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>65</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br /> 
<br /> 
Показать город 
<select id="showTrigger">
    <option selected>Все города</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false
});

$('#showTrigger').change(function () {
    var valText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    var columnNum = 7; // need to fix
    if (valText == 'Все города') {
        for (var i = 1; i <= columnNum; i++) {
            oTable.fnSetColumnVis(i, true);
        }
    } else {
        val = parseInt(valText);
        for (var i = 1; i <= columnNum; i++) {
            if ((val * 2) == i || (val * 2 - 1) == i) {
                oTable.fnSetColumnVis(val * 2, true);
                oTable.fnSetColumnVis(val * 2 - 1, true);
            } else {
                oTable.fnSetColumnVis(i, false);
            }
        }
    }
})
```